# Не могу установить шаблон quick start joomla 4

Tags: php, веб-программирование, joomla, веб-дизайн

Не получается поставить шаблон с joomla 4. База данных создается (вижу его через phpMyAdmin), шаблон устанавливается (ошибок не выдается, загрузка идет (цветные булавки чередуются)), но вот в конце установки перед глазами то же начальное меню мастера установки с параметрами языка и сайта. Ставлю на OpenServer.

Логи

PHP отладка

```
[11-Dec-2022 14:16:44 Europe/Moscow] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in D:\OSPanel\domains\helix3.site\libraries\vendor\joomla\database\src\Mysqli\MysqliStatement.php on line 433
[11-Dec-2022 14:16:44 Europe/Moscow] PHP Warning:  is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(D:\OSPanel\domains\helix3.site\libraries\vendor\symfony\error-handler/Resources/D:\OSPanel\domains\helix3.site\libraries/../templates/system/fatal.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (d:/ospanel/domains;d:/ospanel/userdata/composer;d:/ospanel/userdata/temp;d:/ospanel/modules/system/html/openserver) in D:\OSPanel\domains\helix3.site\libraries\vendor\symfony\error-handler\ErrorRenderer\HtmlErrorRenderer.php on line 353
```

Apache отладка

```
[Sun Dec 11 14:14:03.066776 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 3044:tid 404] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Dec 11 14:14:03.282141 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3044:tid 404] AH00455: Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.0.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 11 14:14:03.282141 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3044:tid 404] AH00456: Server built: Jul 26 2022 23:58:26
[Sun Dec 11 14:14:03.282141 2022] [core:notice] [pid 3044:tid 404] AH00094: Command line: 'D:\\ospanel\\modules\\http\\Apache_2.4-PHP_8.0-8.1+Nginx_1.23\\bin\\httpd.exe -d D:/OSPanel/modules/http/Apache_2.4-PHP_8.0-8.1+Nginx_1.23 -f d:\\ospanel\\modules\\http\\Apache_2.4-PHP_8.0-8.1+Nginx_1.23\\conf\\httpd.conf'
[Sun Dec 11 14:14:03.332012 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3044:tid 404] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3304
[Sun Dec 11 14:14:04.815821 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 3304:tid 432] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
[Sun Dec 11 14:14:05.018882 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3304:tid 432] AH00354: Child: Starting 128 worker threads.
```

Comment: Ну как бы: "PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded", -- увеличьте `max_execution_time`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.